# Timeout error when downloading file using Google Drive Rest API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm getting an error when I download a large file(usually anything bigger than 10mb) from Google Drive using Google Drive Rest API.

```
Operation timed out after 100016 milliseconds with 16476597 bytes received
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using partial downloads? https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#partial_download

Comment: @Gerardo, yup, what I did is limit the requests to 10mb, and redirect the page to requests the next 10mb and so on so forth. The problem is when downloading 100mb+ files, you'd get an error after 10 redirects. And the amount of data received when it's timing out isn't the same as well, sometimes it times-out at 6mb, sometimes even at 2mb.

Comment: I would recommend to make the partial downloads programmatically rather than making the website to redirect many times.

Comment: Any other ideas? I just find it weird that there's a limit.

Comment: I think by default, having too many redirects is found as strange behavior by the browsers. Check for example this issue where having too many redirects is causing problems https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YzvpLaOmVrY